# SMPP packet caused missed call in mobile phone?

Tags: sms, gsm, sms-gateway, smpp

Is there any GSM or SMPP message that could be interpreted as a call instead of an SMS by a mobile phone?
I really appreciate your answer.

For more info:
Sometimes when we send an SMPP packet to the SMSC, the user gets a missed Call in place of an SMS.
We checked the packet with tshark and there was no problem with the format and header.
Please give us any idea to find the problem.

Comment: As far as I know, the answer to your question is that no SMPP message should do this.  I've never heard of it happening before.  Can you narrow it down to a particular phone or operator, or SMS Class (e.g. Class 1)?

Comment: thanks for your answer. we have doubt about this problem. i searched in smpp standard document and there is no filed to cause call instead of sms alarm in mobile phone. in optional parameter a filed with name sms_signal is for alerting mechanism when sms is received by mobile. we create submit_sm with different  service_type and protocol_id. but, no one have this problem.

Comment: What's the SMS class?  Does it happen with more than 1 phone?

Comment: do you mean esm_class?. this value is set to 0. yes it happen for different mobile phone with different brands.

Comment: The only thing that is voice call-related that I can see in SMPP is the esm_class parameter "x x 0 1 1 0 x xShort Message contains Conversation Abort (Korean CDMA)"  I don't know how this works, but you said anyway that your esm_class is 0x00, so this parameter shouldn't be set.  Sorry, I don't know any more.  :-(

Comment: thank you @S List for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Smpp message can do that.
Check ProtocolId and Datacoding fields.